# What way could I add score with different values to my code?

Tags: python

I need to add score to my code and I don't know how. I've tried different ways of previous code I had but they would not work in this program. Any suggestions on what I could do?

I need to make the score so that if the user guesses right on the first try they get 3 points and if they get it on the second they get 1 but if they get it wrong they get none. Here is my code :

```
def choose_song(artist, songs, song_choosen):
    idx = 0
    guess_correct = False
    song = ''
    while idx < 2:
        guess = input('The artist is {} and the song is {}... Enter your guess {}: '.format(artist, song_choosen[:3], idx+1))
        #Iterate through all songs to check if the guess is right, if it is, break out of for loop
        for song in songs:
            if guess.lower().strip() == song.lower().strip():
                guess_correct = True
                song = guess
                break
        #If the user guessed correctly, we are done else try again
        if guess_correct:
            break
        else:
            idx+= 1
    #Show the final output accordingly
    if guess_correct:
        print('You guessed correctly. The song is indeed {} '.format(song))
    else:
        print('You guessed wrong. The song is {} '.format(song_choosen))
choose_song('Eminem', ['Rap God', 'skip'], 'Rap God')
choose_song('Marshmello', ['Project Dreams', 'skip'], 'Project Dreams')
choose_song('Unlike Pluto', ['Late Bloomer', 'skip'], 'Late Bloomer')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to just make it like score=0 and the "if guess_correct:" under it say socre + 1, im not very familiar with adding score which is why im asking for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

- Line 4: `score = 0`
- Line 13 `score = [3,1,0][idx]`
- Line 23 Change `print()` command

Comments on what happens in the follwing new code:

```
idx = 0
guess_correct = False
song = ''
score = 0 #Add Variable for score and set it = 0

while idx < 2:

    guess = input('The artist is {} and the song is {}... Enter your guess {}: '.format(artist, song_choosen[:3], idx+1))

    #Iterate through all songs to check if the guess is right, if it is, break out of for loop
    for song in songs:
        if guess.lower().strip() == song.lower().strip():
            guess_correct = True
            song = guess
            score = [3,1,0][idx] # Depending on your index (number of tries) give 3, 1 or 0 points
            break

    #If the user guessed correctly, we are done else try again
    if guess_correct:
        break
    else:
        idx+= 1

#Show the final output accordingly
if guess_correct:
    print('You guessed correctly. The song is indeed {}. You got {} Points '.format(song, score)) # Print points
else:
    print('You guessed wrong. The song is {}. You got no points '.format(song_choosen)) 


choose_song('Eminem', ['Rap God', 'skip'], 'Rap God')
choose_song('Marshmello', ['Project Dreams', 'skip'], 'Project Dreams')
choose_song('Unlike Pluto', ['Late Bloomer', 'skip'], 'Late Bloomer')
```